# Comcast business modem question

Tags: cisco, juniper

We have a Cisco 2900 router that we use for VPN, and it's connected to a Comcast business modem.  The LAN ip is 10.1.10.2

I also have a Junipe SRX550 firewall that I want to use for VPN, and it's also connected to the same Comcast business modem.  The LAN ip is 10.1.10.3

The VPN works on the Cisco 2900 router, but not on the Juniper SRX550.  I've had Juniper look at my config, and everything is correct.  I was looking at the modem, and I noticed that I have the 10.1.10.2 (Cisco) LAN ip on it for port forwarding, I'm guessing I need to add 10.1.10.2 (Juniper) LAN ip also?

What does port forwarding do?  I did not setup the Cisco router.

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding is a mechanism for use with NAT.

In essence, it says that incoming data directed to a given port should be forwarded to an internal address on a given port.  In your situation, incoming packets, both TCP and UDP ports 500 and 4500, arriving at the Comcast router from outside, will get forwarded to the internal .2: your Cisco router.

You can't forward the same packets to two internal addresses.  If you want, you'll have to run your VPN on different external port numbers for the second VPN, though you should be able to keep the port numbers the same on the Juniper .3.  This of course means the other end has to open the VPN to a different port number.

An alternative is if you have several external IP addresses, in which case you could use one for the Cisco and one for the Juniper, on the natural VPN port numbers.

Comment: The Comcast modem have 4 LAN ports.  The Cisco is connected to one, and the Juniper is connected to a different LAN port on the Comcast modem.  So if I understand correctly, I can just addd 10.1.10.3 to the port forwarding, and use different port numbers.

Comment: ... as far as the port forwarding goes, that's correct.  What is going to be at the other end of the VPN connected to the Juniper?  Are you able to configure the remote ports for that?

Comment: I'm trying to add port 500 for the SRX550 VPN, but it won't let me because, port 500 is already taken for the Cisco VPN.  I can use port 501 for the Juniper SRX550, would that work?

Comment: Just to repeat from my answer: you can't forward the same packets to two internal addresses.  If you change the  forwarded port numbers, you have to change the configuration of the other end of the VPN to match.  What's at the other end?

Comment: ok thank you.  I understand I can't use port 500 again since it's already taken.  The other end is the Juniper SRX550.  I hope I'm answering your question correctly.  I'm new to VPN.  So for Juniper SRX550, I'm using port 551, so I need to tell Juniper SRX550 port 551 is for VPN?

Comment: I was recommended by Juniper to get another static IP just for the Juniper.

Comment: Yes, if you can get multiple static addresses, that's much the best way, and everything is on standard port numbers.  I'll confess I'm confused about what links you're wanting to make, a little sketch would really go a long way, showing the various places you're connecting.